3D interpolation in Python revisited
I have a piece-wise linear path in 3D space, comprising an array of (x, y, z) values, and an array of values giving the distance along the path.  I want to find the distance along the path of other (x, y, z) points which all lie "on" the path (ie the distance to one of the path segments is less than some tolerance).
I found this algorithm
4D interpolation for irregular (x,y,z) grids by python and reproduced the answers.
However, when I use my values, I get an array of nan's.  Would appreciate any suggestions to resolve this - thanks in advance!
import scipy.interpolate
import numpy as np

nodes = np.array([
 [511.03925, 897.2107, 48.937611],
 [499.58658, 889.2893, 49.988685],
 [474.94204, 872.2437, 51.114033],
 [461.30299, 862.8101, 51.072050],
 [450.27944, 855.1856, 50.847374],
 [425.61826, 838.1285, 50.344743],
 [400.95708, 821.0714, 49.842111]])

vals = np.array([3496.03,  3510.00,  3540.00,  3556.59,  3570.00,  3600.00,  3630.00])

pts = np.array([
 [492.09, 884.11, 50.33],
 [482.34, 877.36, 50.78],
 [488.52, 881.64, 50.49],
 [476.24, 873.14, 51.05],
 [482.34, 877.36, 50.78]])

dist = scipy.interpolate.griddata(nodes, vals, pts)
print(dist)


It doesn't seem like this sort of interpolation is what you need. For these data you can throw away all but the first column of pts and calculate the path distance from that.

Since your points all lie on piecewise linear segments, this isn't 3D interpolation; it's 1D interpolation:
import numpy as np

nodes = np.array((
    (511.03925, 897.2107, 48.937611),
    (499.58658, 889.2893, 49.988685),
    (474.94204, 872.2437, 51.114033),
    (461.30299, 862.8101, 51.072050),
    (450.27944, 855.1856, 50.847374),
    (425.61826, 838.1285, 50.344743),
    (400.95708, 821.0714, 49.842111),
))
vals = np.array((
    3496.03,  3510.00,  3540.00,  3556.59,  3570.00,  3600.00,  3630.00,
))
order = nodes[:, 0].argsort()
nodes = nodes[order, :]
vals = vals[order]

pts = np.array((
    (492.09, 884.11, 50.33),
    (482.34, 877.36, 50.78),
    (488.52, 881.64, 50.49),
    (476.24, 873.14, 51.05),
    (482.34, 877.36, 50.78),
))

dist = np.interp(
    x=pts[:, 0], xp=nodes[:, 0], fp=vals,
)
print(dist)

[3519.12564812 3530.99440282 3523.4714383  3538.41998268 3530.99440282]


Hi @Reinderien.  Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, the list of points is not necessarily monotonically increasing or decreasing in x, y or z (eg the next point in the nodes array could be (420., 340., 50.0)) so sorting changes the order of the line segments, which I want to preserve.  Apologies if the example data are misleading
